# False positives when mass testing a low prevalence disease

Tags: probability, bayesian

Assuming you have a test for disease X. The false positive rate of the test is 2%, the true positive rate is 100%. You know that it's a low prevalence disease, only 1% of the population has it. The country has a population of 10 million.
The government implements a mass testing program in order to find out everyone who has it. To save resources, samples from 10 citizens are mixed together to be tested. If it's a positive result, these 10 people are tested again individually to figure out who actually has it.
Given this testing system, how many true negative people will be falsely reported as positive cases?

My incomplete reasoning is as follows:

Let $-$ denote true negative, $+$ denote true positive, $*$ denote the test is positive. For the first 10 mixed test, the probability of person A being negative given the test is positive is:
$$ 
\begin{align} 
p(- | *) &= \frac{p(-)p(* | -)}{p(*)} \\
         &= \frac{p(-)p(* | -)}{p(*|-)p(-) + p(*|+)p(+)}  
\end{align}
$$
We know $p(-) = 0.99, p(+) = 0.01$, $p(*|+) = 1$

I'm a bit stuck on $p(*|-)$ and how to proceed from here. I know $p(*|-)$ has to combine the false positive rate 0.02 and the probability of other 9 people being positive, but not sure how?

Comment: Unless you can show what positive steps you have taken to try and solve it, you may receive a negative response !

Comment: @trueblueanil is the expected number of healthy patients that have been reported positive around $20,741.12$?

Comment: @MatthewH. How did you come up with this number?

Comment: I first found the expected number of groups of $10$ that tested positive after the first round of testing with linearity. Then, for a fixed group of $10$ that tested positive, I calculated the expected number of false positives after the second round of testing. Multiplying these two numbers should yield the expected number of total false positives.